# Android Finish activity error

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have a problem with getting an activity to finish and go back to its parent(right term?) activity.

It gets to this thread ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean) line: 2241
and then gives me an InvocationTargetException.(Throwable) line:50 with the following error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.market.companionpushup/com.android.market.companionpushup.WorkoutActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.android.market.companionpushup/databases/Exercise Data already closed

So I guess I'm confused, how do I have an error dealing with my database when its just trying to finish my activity and go back to the original activity (but never hits onResume method in original Activity).

The code that was called to start the new activity

```
 public void takeRest(int time, int addTime) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("time", time);
    i.putExtra("addTime", addTime);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Then my custom timer runs until I click this button to skip the rest of the timer.  At that point it never goes back to the original activity (I have set breakpoints at onCreate, onStart, onResume, onActivityResult), none of the breakpoints are ever reached without the error.

```
Button skip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            timer.cancel();
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });
```

Other code from original Activity, but is never reached when I step through the debugger

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Toast.makeText(WorkoutActivity.this, "Yay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what you need to know:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.market.companionpushup/com.android.market.companionpushup.WorkoutActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.android.market.companionpushup/databases/Exercise Data already closed
```

What this says is that the database connection used in the `com.android.market.companionpushup.WorkoutActivity` class has been closed, but was needed for something (refilling a ListView, perhaps?). You should examine your `onPause` or `onStop` code in `WorkoutActivity` to ensure that you are not incorrectly closing the database. Are you using `CursorLoader` or `startManagingCursor`?

Comment: But its not even getting back to the original activity.  Currently I have no onPause or onStop methods.  Plus its not even getting to the onResume method

Comment: Which must mean you are closing the database even before you start the new Activity, or you are using a global database connector that is closing in your new Activity. Will be hard to tell what you are doing wrong without looking at your code.

Comment: How is it trying to pull data though?  In the code above there is no data to pull.  onStart, onResume and onActivityResult are all in my code exactly as seen above but none of them are ever being called.  The error occurs after the finish() but before it seems to call anything in my own code...

Comment: I also tried opening the database before I call startActivity and nothing happened.

Comment: The code above is just the piece of YOUR code: it doesn't capture what the framework is doing. The error occurs after the `finish()` but before your code gets called because the Android framework is doing some work to restore the previous Activity and is clearly running into errors with the database (hence the exception). There is an error in the handling of the database: the Activity resume is trying to access it (probably because some View is trying to refresh its data) and failing because the connection has been closed.

Comment: I'll say it again: the problem is not in the activity you are closing, it is in the Activity you are resuming.

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you were saying.  I went through and commented out the times that i called the close() method and it stopped giving the error.

I guess I'm confused how that even causes the problem seeing as those methods are never used after onCreate and I always call open() before its needed.  At least its running now...now I have to figure out which one caused teh error.  THANKS

Comment: Figured it out.  startManagingCursor ties the cursor to the Activity so when the Activity is resumed it tries to load the cursor data and can't because i closed the DB.  If i manually close the cursors(since they aren't needed) everything works good.  w00t!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to start activity with `startActivityForResult()` method?

Comment: Thats what I had originally and changed it to startActivity to try and troubleshoot.